# How to interpret this iOS Instruments data?

Tags: ios, instruments

I have created a sample application which declares a macro as below:

```
#define kSampleString @"didReceiveMemoryWarningdidReceiveMemoryWarningdidReceiveMemoryWarningdidReceiveMemoryWarningdidReceiveMemoryWarningdidReceiveMemoryWarningdidReceiveMemoryWarningdidReceiveMemoryWarningdidReceiveMemoryWarningdidReceiveMemoryWarningdidReceiveMemoryWarningdidReceiveMemoryWarning"
```

When user clicks on the below event handler, I log the Macro string.

```
-(IBAction)SampleMethod:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"Log %@",kSampleString);
}
```

Below is the instruments data I have got:

[image]
On checking the allocations in Instruments, I got the below information. I am able to find that the allocation happens in NSLogv call in the area marked in Red color. But how do interpret  the other things that are happening with respect to NSLogv. What  are those malloc operations happening?

Comment: Who knows what evil lurks in the heart of NSLog?

Comment: @HotLicks [This guy, apparently](http://www.karlkraft.com/index.php/2009/03/23/114/)

Comment: Can't you just see where it's coming from by exposing the extended detail view on the right side? That should show you the stack trace responsible for that allocation.

Comment: @CodaFi -- Doesn't everyone do that?

Comment: @BradLarson - thank you! I never knew that existed. Why does Apple work so hard to make the world's worst UI for tools? Sigh :(.

Answer (score 1):

Malloc is simply the C-version of objective C's alloc, and is eventually called when an alloc is executed.  Instruments is keeping track of all the allocations in your app, so it's only natural that Malloc would show up.

As for the CFString, that is the CoreFoundation cousin of an NSString (because an NSString is a class cluster built around CFString), and you're always supposed to pass NSLog() an immutable string anyhow, so this makes perfect sense.  If your app was leaking memory, then it would be a problem, but for right now, everything is fine.

What I would worry about is that massive 1.5 KB string Malloc about halfway down the list.  That looks like too much memory for a simple string.